# ¿Cómo ordenar una tabla detalle con Sequelize?

Tags: nodejs, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

Intento visualizar una tabla detalle **PostgreSQL** ordenada por su id, pero el motor de la DB lo hace bajo su criterio, que es por fecha de modificación de cada registro. Para esto uso lo habitual, una sentencia SQL que muestre los registros con el orden que necesito, pero no parece tener efecto.

```
var options = {

        where: {mes: req.body.resumen.mes, any: req.body.resumen.any},

        include: [{model: models.Lectura, order: ['id', 'ASC']}],

        order: [
            ['fecha', 'ASC']
        ]

    };


    models.Parte.findAll(options).then(function(partes) {

        res.render('partes/resumen', {partes: partes, errors: []});

    }).catch(function(error){next(error)});
```

En la variable **options** solicito incluir la tabla Lectura con el orden que necesito. El resultado sí incluye la tabla, pero sigue ordenada por fecha de modificación. No hace caso al **order** que solicito.

Se agradece alguna idea.

Answer (score 1):

```
    var options = {

        where: {mes: req.body.resumen.mes, any: req.body.resumen.any},


        include: [{model: models.Lectura}],


        order: [['fecha', 'ASC'], [models.Lectura, 'id', 'ASC' ]]

    };
```

La solución ha sido sencilla.